# Accessing get params in CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, cancan

Is it possible to access parameters passed in the url in CanCan? I'm trying to authenticate guests based on a token in the url.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently achieved something similar using the method described here:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Accessing-request-data

In my case, it looked something like this:

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  ...

  def current_ability
    @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user, params[:token])
  end

end
```

app/models/ability.rb:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user, token=nil)
    ...
    can :read, Article, :tokens => { :token => token }
    ...
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, we are using something similar to
`authorize! action, resource, session[:access_token]` in a before filter - from this page: http://spreecommerce.com/documentation/security.html